# Cutting down trees with squirrel nests

Tags: trees, squirrel

We've got a line of [Siberian elms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulmus_pumila) in our backyard that we want to get rid of. They're not the most attractive tree, they're an invasive species, and they aggressively colonize the lawn. They also have a short lifespan and whether they've reached that or the harsh storms we've had here in the last few years were too much for them, about half seem to be dead or dying.

But the squirrels seem to love them — most of the ones we want to cut down have squirrel nests.

Will the squirrels eventually leave the dead trees? Should we encourage them to leave somehow? Or should we just wait for a day they're not there and cut away, knowing they can restart?